# Как задать смещение балуна относительно метки?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Пытаюсь сместить балун относительно метки в Yandex map API, но не получается:

```
myMap.setCenter(coordinates, 16);
var placemark = new ymaps.Placemark(coordinates,{
    balloonContentHeader: 'qwefgh',
    balloonOffset: [0,40],
});
myMap.geoObjects.add(placemark);
placemark.balloon.open();
```

Как можно сместить балун относительно метки?

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял *balloonOffset* находится в options, и его надо было вывести в отдельные фигурные скобки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения],

```
var placemark = new ymaps.Placemark(coordinates,{
    balloonContentHeader: 'qwefgh',
},
{balloonOffset: [0,-40]});
```

Comment: это не вынести в отдельные фигурные скобки, а третий параметр конструктора. Если вы документацию прочиатете, то первый - коордианиы, потом properties, потом options. Вот доп.опции баллуна написано надо укзазывать в третьем параметре с префиксом. https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Placemark.html#Placemark__param-options

Comment: Спасибо, уже разобрался